# "Runnable::run" - How is this creating an Executor instance?

Tags: java, java-8, runnable, executorservice, executor

I'm working on a project where the following line is used to create a test Executor member variable instance:

`private Executor executor = Runnable::run;`

The code runs and compiles but I don't understand how `Runnable::run` creates an instance of `Executor` since both are different interfaces.

Is anyone able to explain? In particular:

- Where does the implementation of Runnable come from?
- How is it assigned to an `Executor` implementation (since `Executor` is a different interface)?
- What kind of `Executor` is created? e.g. single threaded or pooled
- How would this be written before Java 8?

Thanks.

Comment: [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Executor` is a `@FunctionalInterface`:

```
 public interface Executor {
     void execute(Runnable command);
 }
```

You can re-write it like this to actually understand it better probably:

```
 Executor executor = (Runnable r) -> r.run(); // or Runnable::run
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. 

Where does the Runnable implementation come from? e.g. where is r instantiated?

Comment: @T.R. seems like you need to read a bit what lambda expression are and method references...

Comment: @T.R. `executor` is essentially a function. You give it a runnable to run. That's where the implementation comes from.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I understand now. It was the threading aspect that was confusing me - since `Executor` can be used to control threading - but I think I understand now that all `runnables` passed to this particular executor will run in the same thread.